# Como adquirir o valor do evento onclick()

Tags: javascript, html5, onclick

Quero um "if" que sua condição seja baseada no local do clique do usuário , mas não tenho ideia de como me referir a isso.Acredito que com essa base entendam o que quero que aconteça:

```
if (onclick == window) {executar bloco de código}
```

Caso queira ver meu código:

HTML5:(apenas código revelante)

```
<li><img src="Backgrounds/Foto7.jpg" onclick="myFunction(this.src)"></li>...<div id="open">/*Imagem criada aqui*/</div></body>
```

Javascript

```
function myFunction(a) {
var NewImg = document.createElement('IMG');
document.getElementById('open').appendChild(NewImg);
NewImg.className = "open";
NewImg.setAttribute('src',a);
var DELIMG = document.getElementById('open');
if (onclick == NewImg){DELIMG.removeChild(NewImg)}
}
```

Comment: vc pode se referir a uma div ou um elemento, pelo document.getElementById("suaDiv"), no caso de ser uma div...

Comment: Dessa forma?  if (onclick !== getElementById("minhaDiv")) {}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De modo geral quando queres `if (onclick == window) {executar bloco de código}` usa-se o `.addEventListener`.

Ele pode ser usado em elementos do DOM, na window, em objetos, etc.

No caso de window é simples,

```
window.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    alert('houve um clique na window!');
    alert('O clique foi em cima do elemento ' + e.target.tagName);
});
```

e podes fazer o mesmo em elementos, no caso do teu código poderia fizar assim:

```
NewImg.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    DELIMG.removeChild(NewImg);
});
```

que é a aplicação da ideia que mostras em

```
if (onclick == NewImg){DELIMG.removeChild(NewImg)}
```

Answer (score 2):

Aparentimente o que você quer que seja feito, é que quando a imagem que foi adiconada seja clicada, ela seja deletada. Que talvez seja como no exemplo abaixo:

```js
function myFunction(src) {

  var newImg = document.createElement('img');
  newImg.className = "open";
  newImg.setAttribute('src', src);
  
  var imgOpen = document.getElementById('open');
  imgOpen.appendChild(newImg);
  
  newImg.addEventListener("click", function() {
    imgOpen.innerHTML = '';
  });
  
}
```

```css
.open {
  
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  
}
```

```html
<li>
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/99/Unofficial_JavaScript_logo_2.svg" onclick="myFunction(this.src)" width="100" height="100">
</li>

<div id="open"></div>
```